# is it possible to tell ruby to accept left-hand variables in certain instances?

Tags: ruby

the behavior I'm looking for is so I can define methods to get results like these:

```
> 2i
=> Complex(0,+2i)
> 2²
=> 4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first one, you could add a custom instance methods to `Fixnum` like this:

```
class Fixnum
  def i
    Complex(0, self)
  end
end

> 2.i
# => (0+2i)
```

And as J-_-L pointed out, you could do the same for the second one in Ruby 1.9, though your rb file will need `# encoding: utf-8` at the top.

And as DNNX pointed out, the issue of creating imaginary numbers in Ruby is already addressed by the `Complex` class:

```
require 'complex'
2.im 
#=> (0+2i)
```

Comment: wow that's awesome. :) why wouldn't that work for the second? Ruby has utf-8 support in code doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, just define your method and make sure that you include the magic comment "encoding: utf-8" on line 1 (in 1.9) ;). Unfortunately, the syntax you used in your question is not possible, because it's not valid Ruby syntax. You always have to do it like this: `2.²` or `²(2)` or `² 2`

Comment: this is awesome.. more reasons to love the language

Comment: you're actually reinventing the wheel. The `im` method is already included in Ruby's `complex`: `irb(main):004:0> require 'complex'; 2.im #=> (0+2i)`

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. But Roberto's question was more a general "how do I make these kinds of custom methods" so I think it still fits. Thanks!